# Rails_admin, Date add more accepting formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datepicker, rails-admin

In `rails_admin`, if you have field with `Date` value, it adds datepicker that will help to select date:

[image: date picking]

When I select from datepicker it shows me date in this format: **September 09, 2015**

A lot of users has their birthday year which are in 80's and 90's. It will consume a lot of time to choose proper date.

This makes user to **write date**. Mostly they write in these formats: `mm/dd/yyyy`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, `mm.dd.yyyy` and `dd.mm.yyyy`. When I try to enter date in this format, it throws me an `argument out of range exception`.

It is hard for people to write in **Month name month day, year** format and there will be multiple languages.

How to make rails_admin accept these multiple formats?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rails_admin has many options to override the default behavior.

An example :

```
configure :date_field_name, :date do
  date_format :default
end
```

*:default* referring to a Rails date format : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

You can also provide your own format :

```
configure :date_field_name, :date do
  strftime_format '%Y-%m-%d'
end
```

(http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#strftime-method)

For the other options, see https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/datetime.rb
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/date.rb

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: How do you set default time for the same field? So that say when you open it, it will have the seconds set to 00